# C# adapt code to a button click event

Tags: c#

I am trying to adapt the following code so that the functionality is on a click event ...

Here is the code as is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string IN_FILENAME = @"c:\temp\testin.csv";
        const string OUT_FILENAME = @"c:\temp\testout.csv";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(IN_FILENAME);
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(OUT_FILENAME);

            string inputLine = "";

            while ((inputLine = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                List<string> inputArray = inputLine.Split(new char[] { ',' }).ToList();
                inputArray.Add(inputArray[3]);
                writer.WriteLine(string.Join(",", inputArray));
            }

            reader.Close();
            writer.Flush();
            writer.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Then I need to add the functionality to a click even so this is where I am:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   const string IN_FILENAME = @"c:\temp\testin.csv";
   const string OUT_FILENAME = @"c:\temp\testout.csv";

   StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(IN_FILENAME);
   StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(OUT_FILENAME);
}
```

and I can't do anymore because it's telling me `StreamReader` cannot be found.

Can anyone help me adapt this code to the click event?

Comment: Have  you added this to the top of the page where your click handler is: using System.IO;

Comment: Don't forget to put your stream types in a `using` block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `StreamReader` is a class define in the `System.IO` namespace. Using this namespace at the start of your file, you would resolve it.

```
using System.IO;
```